# Facebook Graph API disable exceptions

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook PHP SDK for my website, and each time I get API error, the SDK returns Exception on website page.

Main question is: How can I disable Exceptions and just receive an errors in GraphObject?

Comment: please provide a code example. Generally - you can wrap your graph api request in `try{ /* your code */ }catch(Exception $e){}`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i fount the solution.

Open **FacebookRequest.php**, find **execute()**.
Near the line 265 find the code like this:

```
if (isset($decodedResult->error)) {
  throw new FacebookRequestException::create(
    $result,
    $decodedResult->error,
    $connection->getResponseHttpStatusCode()
  );
}
```

And just comment or delete this block.